# Update Using Double Quotes

Tags: sql, netezza

I have issue in running the following sql:

```
update personal_view test set session_state="<script type="text/javascript">
alert (mstrApp.sessionState);
</script>"
```

I know it is because of the double quotes within the double quotes and symbols like ; / < and > in the sql.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try:-

```
update personal_view test set session_state='"<script type="text/javascript">'
```

In most SQL dialects strings are wrapped in single quotes double quotes have no special meaning inside a string.